# How to check what shared libraries are loaded at run time for a given process?

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries

Is there a way to check which libraries is a running process using?

To be more specific, if a program loads some shared libraries using [dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen), then readelf or ldd is not going to show it.
Is it possible at all to get that information from a running process? If yes, how?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/310199/how-to-see-the-currently-loaded-shared-objects-in-linux/310205

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Other people are on the right track.  Here are a couple ways.

```
cat /proc/NNNN/maps | awk '{print $6}' | grep '\.so' | sort | uniq
```

Or, with strace:

```
strace CMD.... 2>&1 | grep -E '^open(at)?\(.*\.so'
```

Both of these assume that shared libraries have ".so" somewhere in their paths, but you can modify that.  The first one gives fairly pretty output as just a list of libraries, one per line.  The second one will keep on listing libraries as they are opened, so that's nice.

And of course `lsof`...

```
lsof -p NNNN | awk '{print $9}' | grep '\.so'
```

Comment: Also, `strace -f` is best when child process might be spawned

Comment: You can use the `/proc/self/maps` path where `self` is a symlink to the current process.

Comment: Some improvements for your strace snippet ... (1) Some systems use the openat() syscall instead of open(), (2) people probably want to see versioned DSOs in addition to the unversioned ones, and (3) bash4 syntax is pretty safe to recommend at this point.        `strace CMD ... |& grep '^open.*\.so'`

Comment: @LukeYeager: Not everyone uses Bash, so I like to keep bashisms out of shell snippets.

Comment: nice answer, fyi, you need to escape the second open paren `(` in your strace grep.

Comment: `strace` can't show when you open a library via `dlopen`

Comment: @PersianGulf: How does dlopen work, if not by opening the library?

Answer (score 19):

May be `lsof` - the swiss army knife of linux will help?

edit: to run, `lsof -p <pid>`, lists all sorts of useful information, for example, if the process is java, lists all the open jars - very cool...

Comment: lsof seams to be the solution. Can you add an example how to call lsof on a process that is already running?

Answer (score 15):

Actually, you can do this in your code in the following way:

```
#include <link.h>

using UnknownStruct = struct unknown_struct {
   void*  pointers[3];
   struct unknown_struct* ptr;
};
using LinkMap = struct link_map;

auto* handle = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW);
auto* p = reinterpret_cast<UnknownStruct*>(handle)->ptr;
auto* map = reinterpret_cast<LinkMap*>(p->ptr);

while (map) {
  std::cout << map->l_name << std::endl;
  // do something with |map| like with handle, returned by |dlopen()|.
  map = map->l_next;
}
```

The `link_map` structure contains at least the base address and the absolute file name. It's the structure that is actually returned by `dlopen()` with non-NULL first argument. For more details see [here](http://syprog.blogspot.ru/2011/12/listing-loaded-shared-objects-in-linux.html).

Comment: Ha! So ugly, but it works. Would there be any documentation about the so called "unknown_struct"?

Comment: The same should work with dlinfo() called with RTLD_DI_LINKMAP (see "man dlinfo")

Comment: This works for me without using the "unknown_struct"

    #include <link.h>
    #include <iostream>
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        struct link_map* map = reinterpret_cast<struct link_map*>(dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW));
        map = map->l_next->l_next;
        while (map) {
            std::cout << map->l_name << std::endl;
            map = map->l_next;
        }
    }

Answer (score 12):

`ltrace` seems to be your friend.

From `ltrace` manual:

> ltrace  is  a  program  that simply
>   runs the specified command until it
>              exits.  It intercepts and records the dynamic library calls 
>   which  are
>              called  by  the  executed process and the signals which are
>   received by
>              that process.  It can also intercept and print the  system  calls
>   exe‐
>              cuted by the program.
>
> ```
>        Its use is very similar to strace(1).
> ```

Answer (score 7):

On Linux, `/proc/<processid>/maps` contains a list of all the files mapped into memory, which I believe should include any loaded by `dlopen()`.

Answer (score 4):

On solaris there is also the pldd command.

Comment: Exists on Linux too. Really seems a lot easier than the other proposed commands.

Comment: On Linux, pldd is part of the glibc package so should be everywhere. But according to its man page it didn't actually work until a few years ago.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so programmatically on Linux. You can use the function [`dl_iterate_phdr`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dl_iterate_phdr).

Here is a small example taken from the man page :

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <link.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int
callback(struct dl_phdr_info *info, size_t size, void *data)
{
    int j;

   printf("name=%s (%d segments)\n", info->dlpi_name,
        info->dlpi_phnum);

   for (j = 0; j < info->dlpi_phnum; j++)
         printf("\t\t header %2d: address=%10p\n", j,
             (void *) (info->dlpi_addr + info->dlpi_phdr[j].p_vaddr));
    return 0;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    dl_iterate_phdr(callback, NULL);

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Would `strace` trace the library file being opened?

Answer (score 0):

The question is whether you want to know it about a foreign process:

```
$ sleep 1h&p=$!;sleep 0.1;gdb -p $p -batch -ex 'info shared'
[1] 637756
...
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007f795ffc4700  0x00007f7960135aed  Yes         /lib64/libc.so.6
0x00007f79601cc0a0  0x00007f79601f2d35  Yes         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
[Inferior 1 (process 637756) detached]
```

Or about your own process:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <link.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <dlfcn.h>
int main() {
  // prevent R_X86_64_COPY and r_state inconsistency if we accessed "_r_debug" directly.
  r_debug *debug = (r_debug *) dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "_r_debug");
  assert(debug);
  assert(debug->r_version == 1);
  assert(debug->r_state == r_debug::RT_CONSISTENT);
  link_map *prev = NULL;
  for (link_map *map = debug->r_map; map; prev = map, map = map->l_next) {
    assert(map->l_prev == prev);
    std::cout << map << " " << (!map->l_name[0] ? "<empty>" : map->l_name) << std::endl;
  }
}
```