# How can I check a running process to see what shared libraries it is using?

Tags: c++, linux, runtime, dlopen, ldd

On Linux, I have a C++ application that is using dlopen() to load some shared libraries, but I'm suspicious that the version of the shared library being loaded is not the one I expect because my debugging trace code does not appear to be executed.

Is there a way to check a running process to query all the shared libraries it currently has open and the path to each of those libraries?  In other words, something akin to `ldd` but that works on a running executable and lists runtime loaded libraries as well.

Comment: try `lsof -p _process_id_`

Comment: K here is a full answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103443/how-to-check-what-shared-library-is-loaded-at-run-time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to know the library files a program have opened, you can try pmap.
For example, if we want to know the libraries that bash process 3860 have opened, the result could be:

```
3860:   bash
08048000    880K r-x--  /bin/bash
08124000      4K r----  /bin/bash
08125000     20K rw---  /bin/bash
0812a000     20K rw---    [ anon ]
099ae000    348K rw---    [ anon ]
b715c000     44K r-x--  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
b7167000      4K r----  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
b7168000      4K rw---  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
b7169000     88K r-x--  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.15.so
b717f000      4K r----  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.15.so
b7180000      4K rw---  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.15.so
b7181000      8K rw---    [ anon ]
b7183000     28K r-x--  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.15.so
b718a000      4K r----  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.15.so
b718b000      4K rw---  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.15.so
b71a1000      4K r----  /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
b71a2000   1428K r----  /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
b7307000   2048K r----  /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
b7507000      4K rw---    [ anon ]
b7508000   1676K r-x--  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b76ab000      8K r----  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b76ad000      4K rw---  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b76ae000     16K rw---    [ anon ]
b76b2000     12K r-x--  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
b76b5000      4K r----  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
b76b6000      4K rw---  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
b76b7000    112K r-x--  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
b76d3000      8K r----  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
b76d5000      4K rw---  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
b76d8000     28K r--s-  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
b76df000     40K r-x--  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
b76e9000      4K r----  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
b76ea000      4K rw---  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
b76eb000      8K rw---    [ anon ]
b76ed000      4K r-x--    [ anon ]
b76ee000    128K r-x--  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b770e000      4K r----  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b770f000      4K rw---  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
bfbbf000    132K rw---    [ stack ]
 total     7152K
```

Wish it would be of help for you.

Comment: Had to run a program through GDB to keep it alive long enough, but pmap does the job. Thanks!