# Finding Library Location in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I'm working on a Java project with a native library in question. I believe that another version is being loaded when I try to use it from a non-Netbeans environment- when I debug the file in Netbeans, it works as expected, but when I run it from anywhere else, it hits a "NoSuchMethodError", leading me to believe that there is another instance (in the wrong version) being loaded

I've already examined my java.library.path and removed all other instances of the library beyond the dist/lib, but the error persists. Is there an easy way to find the location of a loaded library, so that I might be able to find out what is happening?

Comment: you can see imported libraries in netbeans in library section of your project

Comment: I'm not concerned about the Netbeans run- I'm concerned about how it's running when it's NOT in NetBeans. I'm inclined to think there's something else afoot.

Comment: java.library.path is for native libraries, not class libraries. Have you tried running with `-verbose:class` to see where the class is loaded from?

Comment: Are you on a Linux?  Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103443/how-to-check-what-shared-library-is-loaded-at-run-time) could help.

Comment: Is it possible to enable verbose:class in the Java console?