# How to get paths of loaded shared libraries in a C program on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I'd like to detect if the Steam overlay has been loaded in my program, which is using `LD_PRELOAD` with a `gameoverlayrenderer.so`. I would use `dlopen` with `RTLD_NOLOAD` to check, but unfortunately the path of the shared library is not in `LD_LIBARY_PATH` and the full path differs between setups.

Is there a way to get a full list of shared libraries loaded in my program so that I can manually search the list of paths for the string `gameoverlayrenderer.so`? Essentially the equivalent of [`EnumProcessModules`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: You essentially need the information at `/proc/self/maps`, open that file and dump it's content to figure out how to use it. `/proc/self/` helps you avoid building the path of the `maps` file with the process *pid*.

Comment: @iharob Is reading that file the cleanest way to do it?

Comment: Yes, as many things in linux. It's probably similar to the way `EnumProcessModules` works internally. But reading from `/proc/self/` directory is realy reliable. The `proc` filesystem is a special filesystem that is mounted when the system boots, it's always mounted and every process is guaranteed to have an entry in the `/proc` directory AFAIK.

Comment: I think this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27522149/2668109) might be of help.

Comment: @iharob I just found [dl_iterate_phdr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dl_iterate_phdr), which seems to do the same as well.

Comment: Yes and [the link](http://syprog.blogspot.ru/2011/12/listing-loaded-shared-objects-in-linux.html) at the answer seems interesting too.

Comment: @iharob Hah, that's perfect. Thanks.

Comment: But please read the manual page [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html).

Comment: @iharob I did, but it's only mentioned at the bottom in related.