# Get dynamic library directory in c++ (linux)

Tags: c++, linux

Is there any programmatic way to get the location of a dynamic library loaded by a program?

I know that it is possible to get the 'executable' running path. But it is not enough for me.

I'm developing an external library that has some dependencies and I need to point accordingly to its location.

For example, the program is running at:

```
/local/deepLearning/bin
```

And this program uses a dynamic library located at:

```
/local/external/libs/faciesAnalysis
```

What I need is, at runtime, the string

```
"/local/external/libs/facesAnalysis"
```

I am working on linux, any suggestion?

Comment: Some versions of linux provide additional dlopen support for this.

Comment: have a look at this duplicate question [How to get paths of loaded shared libraries in a C program on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32934274/how-to-get-paths-of-loaded-shared-libraries-in-a-c-program-on-linux)

Comment: http://syprog.blogspot.ru/2011/12/listing-loaded-shared-objects-in-linux.html

Comment: You should really explain why you need this.... So **edit your question** to improve it

Comment: I finally downvoted this question (unclear, because you don't give any reasons or motivations)

Answer (score 11):

Since this is specifically Linux, `dladdr()` is a glibc extension to the `dl` family of functions that will lookup the filename of any symbol.  Pass it the address of any function that you know exists in the library you are looking for, and you're basically done.

Presented without appropriate error checking:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>

const char *my_fname(void) {
    Dl_info dl_info;
    dladdr((void*)my_fname, &dl_info);
    return(dl_info.dli_fname);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First (and this is specific to Linux, since provided by the kernel), you can parse the `/proc/self/maps`  pseudo-file from inside your program. Just read sequentially every line of that textual file, you'll be able to get the full path of every `mmap`-ed file, including shared libraries. See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) (and use [dirname(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dirname.3.html) to get a directory out of a path, perhaps also [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html)...). Read also [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) & [ld-linux.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.so.8.html) and notice the role of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `/etc/ld.so.conf`

Then, and this is specific to [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (but apparently [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) also has that), you could use [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) on some function address from that library. Or just use [dl_iterate_phdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html) which looks exactly fit to your question.

Beware of weird cases: some program might generate a plugin and `dlopen` it later (my [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) is doing [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26002308/841108)), some other program might `remove` a plugin after `dlopen`, some programs might be statically linked, the `dlopen`-ed plugin could have been moved or renamed (perhaps because a new version has been installed while your program is running)..., the same plugin could have been symlinked and dlopened using different paths, etc...

Read Drepper's paper: [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You could get the full path to the executable (`std::string path_and_exe`) and then execute the following:

```
#include <cstdlib>
std::string output("output.txt");

system ("ldd " + path_and_exe + " > " + output);

// read libray paths from output file
```

Comment: At lease suggest a `popen` but actually this is not very needed. Just use `/proc/self/maps` as suggested by my answer (faster, less dependency on external resources)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch was in a great hurry and saw nobody was helping OP so rattles off first (rather poor) solution that came to mind