# Check shared object from a python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, shared-libraries, .so

lets assume that I have the following python script :

`python_script.py`

```
import os 
import subprocess 

subprocess.Popen(['python2',os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"),"test","top_block.py")])
```

I have to check if this subprocess is calling a particular shared library (lib_modified.so). If it's true go ahead with the execution otherwise stop it.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `if "lib_modified.so" in open(the_filename).read(): execute_script(); else: dont_execute_script()`?

Comment: What do you mean? Inside the python_script.py there are no references to lib_modified.so. It uses some APIs provided by this lib. Just this.

Comment: I mean you should check `top_block.py` for the string "lib_modified.so", not `python_script.py`.

Comment: ah sorry. I was wrong. Inside top_block.py there are no reference to lib_modied.so.

Comment: Then how do you know that top_block.py is calling lib_modified.so? Sorry, I'm not terribly familiar with shared libraries.

Comment: Ah no problem me too :). I know it because it's a script to run a flowgraph into GNURadio using UHD , so it calls for sure libuhd.so.

Comment: do you want to check for debugging purpose or do you want an automate way to check it ? in the first case it looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5103443/128629

Comment: I would like find an automate way to check it, or a way to build a function to do it. Btw now i will check the discussion that you suggested. Thanks