# Java / JNI leaking Dynamic libraries

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

My process is running C++ calls to Java by JNI running at a Suse.
  After some days working I'm having a memory issue regarding the JVM:

## There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

## Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.

With the following trace:

```
V  [libjvm.so+0xaba71a]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x2ba
V  [libjvm.so+0x4f9ecb]  report_vm_out_of_memory(char const*, int, unsigned long, VMErrorType, char const*)+0x8b
V  [libjvm.so+0x91b553]  os::Linux::commit_memory_impl(char*, unsigned long, bool)+0x103
V  [libjvm.so+0x91b61c]  os::pd_commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, bool)+0xc
V  [libjvm.so+0x9150da]  os::commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, bool)+0x2a
V  [libjvm.so+0x9197ef]  os::pd_create_stack_guard_pages(char*, unsigned long)+0x7f
V  [libjvm.so+0xa603ce]  JavaThread::create_stack_guard_pages()+0x5e
V  [libjvm.so+0x6cd4e4]  attach_current_thread+0xb4
```

The machine has plenty of memory (a few Terabytes) so its quite impossible that this is caused by a normal machine going out of memory and not being able to grow the reserved java heap.

By seeing the remaining of the report I can see that I have 65535 entries for dynamic libraries like this:

```
7326707ff000-732670801000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
732670801000-732671000000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
732671000000-73269d400000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
73269d5ff000-73269d602000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
```

My questions:

1. How can I dump the dynamic libraries that the Java process is using?
2. Is there any limit on the number of dynamic libraries that the JVM
   can control (similar to XMX)?

Comment: ake a look at stack size. Maybe issue is related to the stack size in JVM. Note that each and every Thread has it's own stack: -Xss

Comment: 1. Java process is not differnet in this sense from any other process. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103443/how-to-check-what-shared-libraries-are-loaded-at-run-time-for-a-given-process

Comment: This issue seems related to the tuning suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux